# how to give customized name in zend 2 form

Tags: php, zend-framework2

how to create a custom attribute name using zend 2 form , i need to create attribute name like below

```
<input type="text" name="USER[FIRSTNAME]" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend 2 uses square brackets for its fieldsets.

If you do:

```
$form = new Form();
$fieldset = new Fieldset('USER');
$input = new Text('FIRSTNAME');
$fieldset->add($input);
$form->add($fieldset);
```

You will get this when you render the form:

```
<fieldset>
   <input type="text" name="USER[FIRSTNAME]" value="">
</fieldset>
```